# Error occured during local report processing in C# after installing to other computer

Tags: c#, report

I developed this C# application and it works perfectly in my pc. So I created an installer for this app then tried to install it in my computer, and it still works without error and exception.

But when I tried to install it to other computer, I encountered an exception: 
.

> An error occurred during local report processing.

Then my report viewer doesn't show the data that should be shown, but it shows the error message i think.

> An error occurred during local report processing. 
>       The definition of the report is invalid. 
>       An unexpected error occurred in Report Processing.
>       Could not load file or assembly "Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
>       PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91 or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I use System.Data.OleDb as my connection on my connection to my MS Access Database.

As i've said, the installed application perfectly works in my computer, until I install it to other pc. I don't know if what's wrong.

Comment: Have a read of http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2013/12/09/microsoft-sqlserver-types-nuget-package-spatial-on-azure.aspx. This *may* fix your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to download the SqlServer.Types dll's and install it to other computer, but still my application didn't work (same problem occurs). 
.
Then after following these steps.

Step 1: On the Visual C# Project, select

> Tab >> Library Package Manager >> Manage NuGet Packages for Solution

Step 2:

> Select the Online Tab and Search ReportViewer

Step 3:

> Select Microsoft.ReportViewer.Windows and install it.

After those steps, I create an another installer for my application and when I install it to other computer, It works perfectly without error or exceptions. 
.
Thanks for your help. Really Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

The things you need to check:

1. Is the Microsoft SQL Server Feature Pack installed?

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26728

2. Is the there office package installed?
3. Is the access database engine installed?

Those should be present.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your problem is in the error message.

> An error occurred during local report processing. The definition of
>   the report is invalid. An unexpected error occurred in Report
>   Processing. Could not load file or assembly
>   "Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91 or one of its dependencies. The system
>   cannot find the file specified.

In your computer, you have a set of DLL's that are required to run your application. They (the DLL's) are already there, so, an installer, even if missing one or more of the files in the installer, will not cause problem to the program.

In the other computer, you are missing one or more DLL's required by your program, and your installer is not providing them.

So, you are missing the Microsoft.SqlServer.Types assembly in the other computer, or a required DLL to run it.